# Sorting multidimensional array without pointers

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

Ok, so I've got multidimensional array "int Array[3][4];" so let's say for instance I have such scanned information:

```
2 5 6 4 
3 4 8 3 
1 8 8 7
```

So I need to sort every column (growing) Like so:

```
1 4 6 3 
2 5 8 4 
3 8 8 7
```

So I'd like to ask you how can I sort such multidimensional array without using pointers? Previously I used bubble method, however I couldn't get it working this time...

My code example:

```
  for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(z=i+1;z<4;z++){
        if(Array[i][z-1]>Array[i][z]) {
            int x=Array[i][z-1];
            Array[i][z-1]=Array[i][z];
            Array[i][z]=x;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Bubble sorting ought to work here, so you must be doing something else wrong. We can't tell what.

Comment: Post what you tried so far and explain where you ran into difficulty

Comment: Just updated my post, what I don't get is how to sort by columns

Comment: `Array[i][z-1]>Array[i][z]` --> `Array[i-1][z]>Array[i][z]` should be focused towards the `i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the number of elements  to compare is 3 , So it can be as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){    
    int Array[3][4] = {
        2, 5, 6, 4,
        3, 4, 8, 3,
        1, 8, 8, 7
    };
    int i,j;
    int min, max, mid;
    int min_i, max_i;

    for(i=0;i<4;++i){
        max_i = Array[0][i] < Array[1][i];
        min_i = !max_i;
        if(Array[min_i][i] > Array[2][i])
            min_i = 2;
        if(Array[max_i][i] < Array[2][i])
            max_i = 2;
        max=Array[max_i][i];
        mid=Array[3-max_i-min_i][i];
        min=Array[min_i][i];
        Array[0][i]=min;
        Array[1][i]=mid;
        Array[2][i]=max;
    }
    for(i=0;i<3;++i){
        for(j=0;j<4;++j)
            printf("%d ", Array[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```